# Optional Parameters in .aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, optional-parameters

I have a static method (in the class CommonHelper in the namespace Common) that I want to use for including static resources that has a definition like the following:

```
public static string GetUrlForStaticResource(
String fileName, String folder="scripts", bool preventCaching=false)
```

You can see the "folder" and "preventCaching" parameters are optional as they have default values. When I call the method from a .cs file it works fine but in my .aspx I tried the following and got an error **CS1501: No overload for method 'GetUrlForStaticResource' takes '1' arguments**:

```
<div>Example: <%= Common.CommonHelper.GetUrlForStaticResource("test.js") %></div>
```

If I provide all the parameters it works fine:

```
<div>Example: <%= Common.CommonHelper.GetUrlForStaticResource("test.js", "scripts", false) %>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Are optional parameters not available in .aspx?

Comment: That's awkward. Both classes (the one that has the `GetUrlForStaticResource` and the ASPX.CS) are on the same project?

Comment: It should work. All is right. Check whether you import namespace of your Common class on your aspx

Comment: Yes on the same project it works in the .aspx.cs file but not in the .aspx file. The only thing I can think of is something weird happening with the C# Version. I have the project set to .NET 3.5 but it is running on .Net 2.0 which is interesting.

Comment: check your application pool - does it use v4.0?

Comment: please show us the namesapce of .aspx and where this method lives

Comment: One possibility is that Common doesn't have a default static constructor, but has a static constructor that requires parameters.

Comment: I should have made it more clear that Common is the namespace and CommonHelper is the class. @BurundukXP: How do I check that?

Comment: @HatSoft The namespace is Common.

Comment: @tom_yes_tom CommonHelper doesn't have any constructor defined. Do I need to?

Comment: do you use IIS? if yes go to IIS, than check base settings of your website - you'll see the name of your application pool. and than go to the applications pool list (above the lit of your websites in the lefthand tree) and check .NET version for associated pool

Comment: I tested this and it works fine for me. I used .NET 4.0 and CommonHelper as a static class (with no explicit constructor). I then changed the web project to .NET 2.0. The project builds, and then I get the same error you report at runtime.

Comment: Aren't optional parameters a feature of C# 3.0 or 4.0? Not going to work with .NET 2.0 (C# 2.0).

Comment: @styfle If you have defined no constructor, it should be fine.  A default constructor is created for you.

Comment: @James I think you're right on this one. Post that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this and it works fine for me. I used .NET 4.0 and CommonHelper as a static class (with no explicit constructor).

I then changed the web project to .NET 2.0. The project builds, and then I get the same error you report at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you could also create an overload for GetUrlForStaticResource that only accepts one parameter, and then call the primary method from there with the default values.

Comment: True but default parameters is so elegant. You write the method documentation once instead of 3 times. It just seems odd that it would work in the code behind perfectly fine. Even visual studio intellisense is showing me the optional params. It's just a runtime error.